# Excel MATCH doesn't MATCH

Tags: excel-formula

The following formula returns #N/A.

```
=MATCH(1,SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(U5,ROW(U5:U400)-ROW(U5),0)),0)
```

If I highlight "SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(U5,ROW(U5:U400)-ROW(U5),0))" and hit F9, I'd get an array of 0 and 1.

The question is: why doesn't MATCH find 1 in the array? As the matter of fact, MATCH doesn't find 0 either.

Comment: Are you entering the formula with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: Can you show an example of data you are trying to apply this formula for?

Comment: @Scott, I tried Ctrl-Shift-Edit and it worked. That's not really what I want though. I avoid using array formula in general. Anyway, why it needs an array formula? Why simple Enter would not work?

Comment: Any time you are returning an array from a formula to MATCH 2nd criterion it will need to be entered as an array formula.

Comment: If you want to avoid the Array entry you can use: `=AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW(U5:U400)-ROW(U5)+1)/SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(U5,ROW(U5:U400)-ROW(U5),0)),1)` But this is still an array formula, It just is native and does NOT need to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: The only way to not have an array formula would be to have a helper column where you put the subtotal formula: `=SUBTOTAL(2,U5)` and copy down the range.  Then a simple match: `=MATCH(1,Z5:Z400,0)` where `Z5:Z400` is the helper column.  This would avoid both the volatile `OFFSET` and the Array formulas.

Comment: Thanks. The only reason I avoid array formula is I don't want to hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter. If I don't have to do it, I can accept array formula.